# GPS Location Permission box not appering

Tags: iphone, xcode, permissions, gps

I am trying to make a gps location app in which it gets the users latitude and longitude.I want to request the location when user starts the app .

```
if([self.locationManager                                                                     
      respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
{

    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}

else

{

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

But its not helping i also try

```
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){

    NSLog(@"Location Services Enabled");

    if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied){
        UIAlertView    *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App Permission Denied"
                                                           message:@"To re-enable, please go to Settings and turn on Location Service for this app."
                                                          delegate:nil
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Its not helping also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add a key for location request
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in your plist file
and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key if you want location in background also.